# Targeting Android Voice Recognition

Tags: android, voice-recognition

I'm writing an early learner flashcard game app for training sight words (e.g. "and", "be", "dog", "if", "play", etc).

I'm using voice recognition to display the word to be read and then recognize what the user says.

When the app is displaying "a", and I say "a", recognition comes back with "hey". I've already had to add some code to use the [apache soundex](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/language/Soundex.html) to clear up some homonyms, and some more code to translate the numerical homonyms (2/to, 1/won, 8/ate, etc) to the letter equivalents so the soundex can work.

How can I give voice recognition a restricted list of words to choose from?

Comment: You can use CMUSphinx with grammar. See http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialandroid

Comment: Actually there is such a question already